# Pattern matching using a variable in SED

Tags: sed

Consider the below code:

```
pattern="*.some_pattern.*"
orignalLogFile='sample.log'
outputFile='1.txt'
temp='1.log'

# match the pattern and replace with a new line
sed 's/'$pattern'/\n/' $orignalLogFile > $temp
```

Throws a

> 'sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command'

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need two corrections

The `*.` in your pattern does not make sense, so

```
pattern=".*some_pattern.*"
```

Also, you need to pass the pattern in double-quotes to protect it from shell expansion

```
sed 's/'"$pattern"'/\n/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed won't accept newline characters.  AFAIK it also won't accept stars, either; but I don't think you will need to use those.

```
pattern="some_pattern"
orignalLogFile='sample.log'
outputFile='1.txt'

read -r < "${originalLogFile}"

echo "${REPLY}" | sed s"@${pattern}@newline@" > newlog.tmp

read newlog < newlog.tmp

echo "${newlog}" | tr 'newline' '\n' > "${outputFile}"
rm newlog.tmp
```

Comment: Using directly the pattern without having it in a variable works fine. sed takes substitutes newlines for the pattern

sed 's/.*patterntomatch.*/\n/' sample.log > newLog.txt

This works fine. Prob is when i have "patterntomatch" in a variable.

Comment: That might work for GNU sed in Linux, yes; but that is not POSIX compliant, and hence not portable.  The solution I have given you works for FreeBSD, and is therefore portable; it will work with OSX and presumably any other UNIX.

GNU utilities have extensions which break the POSIX standard; that is one big reason why I don't write scripts under Linux.

Also, you can get around the variable not working with sed, by putting it in double quotes rather than single, like I have there.